# There is a problem with the declaration of array during serialization of json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I received the Json file using API in c#.

While serializing the data, there was a problem with the arry.

```
{
   "features":[
      {
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               126.0,
               37.0
            ]
         },
      },
      {
         "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  126.0,
                  37.0
               ],
               [
                  126.0,
                  37.0
               ]
            ]
         },
      }
   ]
}
```

This is part of the json file.
And the "coordinates" array is repeated, but one is one dimensional and the other is two dimensional.
I don't know how to declare this. This is my code.
How should I declare the **geometry** class?

```
public class JsonClass
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<features> features { get; set; }
}

public class features
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public properties properties { get; set; }
}

       
public class geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public float[] coordinates { get; set; }
    //or public float[,] coordinates { get; set; }?
    //both error...
}
```

Please understand that I used a translator because I couldn't speak English.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it was tested in VS 2022

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

classes

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("features")]
    public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}

public partial class Feature
{
    [JsonProperty("geometry")]
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }
}

public partial class Geometry
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("coordinates")]
    public List<object> _coordinates
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != null && value.Count > 0)
                if (double.TryParse(value[0].ToString(), out _))
                {
                    Coordinates1D = value.Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x)).ToList();
                }
                else
                    Coordinates2D = value.Select(x =>  ((JArray)x).ToObject<List<double>>()).ToList();
        }
    }

    public List<double> Coordinates1D { get; set; }
    
    public List<List<double>> Coordinates2D { get; set; }
}
```

but fix your json before

```
{
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    126.0,
                    37.0
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        126.0,
                        37.0
                    ],
                    [
                        126.0,
                        37.0
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I just tested with this code. And this code solved what I had been thinking about for 5 hours at once. For me, this code is close to art. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Harry  You are very welcome!